# How to map a handful of numbers in a large range to a much smaller range deterministically without collissions

Tags: hash, random-number-generator

I want to map a set of long integers (say around 100 different values) that can span the entire 64 bit integer range to a much smaller range such as from 0 to 25000 deterministically with almost zero collisions. This operation has to be very fast as well.

Please not that, generating random numbers in the expected range is not a solution, as the original numbers are created by an external system.

EDIT:
Would a pairing function such as following qualify above criteria. From this article, it seem to qualify, but I would like some expert advice.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function

Comment: Does the "deterministically" part rule out [universal hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_hashing)? $\;$

Comment: I am not familiar with universal hashing, but if this involves picking up the hashing function based on data, it might, as in my case the order in which the system encounter original Numbers may differ.

Comment: It specifically can avoid picking the hashing function based on data. $\;$

Comment: If you know the 100 different integers beforehand, this is known as "perfect hashing"; google for that